# Finding angles from an IMU (Quaternions to Eulers)

Tags: java, geometry

Greetings and apologies if this has already been answered, but I haven't been able to get a clear answer from looking on Stack Exchange so-far.

I have Quaternions coming from two different IMU's located on the trunk and the back of the head, in order to describe relative rotations between both.

Of course if I would make use of the Euler transform for each of the IMU´s (and subtract to find the relative angles), gimbal locks manifest. But we SHOULDN'T have that problem if we were to represent the relative angles (which is the case, because the aim of this is to show an angular representation that a physiotherapist can understand), because relatives are quite small angles, and probably won't go near +-90.

So what I have in mind is taking the quaternion Q1 that represents the trunk IMU and the quaternion Q2 that represents the head, find the quaternion that rotates Q1 into Q2 (let´s call it Qr) and transform THAT ONE into Eulers.

And it... works. But for some reason I have a "crosstalk" between the pitch and the roll, meaning that they are NOT independent between them.

Is this procedure flawed? What would be a better approach to this?

Comment: When you have 2 different ways to solve a problem and they give similar results, one can reasonably assume that the more cleaver solution works.  I don’t know of a better solution but someone might, but that is a roll of the dice.  Wouldn’t comparison with an alternative method be more reliable?